# ReactJS Server-Side Babel-Core PNG error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

### The situation:

I've built a web app with ReactJS full client-side. It is working great.

### My desire:

Change my app to render from server-side.

### The problem:

I'm facing problems to precompile with `babel` due some `.png` file.

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "web.facundolarocca.com",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "config": "^1.24.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "no-if-validator": "^1.0.0-4",
    "nodemailer": "^2.7.0",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-responsive": "^1.2.6",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.5.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start:dev": "babel-node server/server.js",
    "start:dev:nodemon": "nodemon server/server.js --exec babel-node",
    "build:prod": "babel server/server.js -d build-server",
    "server:start": "node build-server/server.js"
  },
  "standard": {
    "global": [
      "it"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Server route

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import reducer from '../src/reducers/index'
import App from '../src/containers/App'

// server.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')))
server.use('/', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware
    )
  )

  // Render the component to a string
  const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  )

  // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
  const preloadedState = store.getState()
  // Send the rendered page back to the client
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
})

let renderFullPage = (html, preloadedState) => {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
        </script>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}
```

### Console error:

> SyntaxError:
>   C:/.../src/images/background.png:
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:0) [0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 1 |
>   [39m�PNG  [90m   | [39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m  [90m 2 |
>   [39m[37m[41m[1m[22m[49m[39m  [90m 3 | [39m[37m[41m[1m
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "start:dev"
>   npm ERR! node v7.0.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! web.facundolarocca.com@0.1.0 start:dev: `babel-node
>   server/server.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at
>   the web.facundolarocca.com@0.1.0 start:dev script 'babel-node
>   server/server.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of
>   node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a
>   problem with the web.facundolarocca.com package, npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
>   ERR!     babel-node server/server.js npm ERR! You can get information
>   on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   web.facundolarocca.com npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can
>   get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls web.facundolarocca.com
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Projects\web.facundolarocca.com\npm-debug.log

I guess I should tell to babel to avoid compiling those kinds of files, but I cant find how neither other solution. I ended up following the simples tutorial I've found: [Server Rendering - Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html)

I removed the whole server-code because I thought I was cleaner, but If think I should include it, feel free to ask me.

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the `babeljs` tag because this isn't related to Babel. That error is from Node's core. You'd get the same thing if you tried to `require()` a PNG file. You're telling Node to import a PNG file, and Node has no idea what you want it to do with them.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, but I already know the problem, what I cant figure out is how to solve it.

Comment: Sounds good, I just wanted to clarify that this is a general Node issue, not one specific to Babel.